# Setting/Changing, storing and reusing a custom gradient drawable programmatically

Tags: android

i am trying to let the user of my app customize its appearance. The user can set the gradient values for backgrounds, buttons and other controls/views. This is working quite well but i dont get an idea how to save and later retrieve the setting i.e. for a customized background setting.
Is there a way to save the gradient drawables setting in shared preferences or save these things as xml drawable and then let the app use that special customized drawable background ? Or are there better approches to reach that goal? Perhaps saving the settings in a database?

I thought of two drawable xml files for the apps backround (default_background.xml and custom_background.xml) and to choose between those programtically if a boolean pref is set to use custom colors is true...
But it doesnt seem to be possible to modify the custom file at runtime.

i've searched a lot but dont seem to find a proper answer... edit:(or cant find/imagine the right search terms)

perhaps someone here has an idea?

regards
Marco

edit: to perhaps better understand what i am trying to do

normally i define the background of the view/activity, lets say a linear_layout ( main.xml), by creating a drawable xml (bg.xml) file and then set the background property to  bg.xml

now the application is started by the user. the user sets the background the way he likes the app to look to. I made a graphicSettings activity for this task. Now i am looking for a nice way to get the new customized background loaded in all (defined) activties. So every layout that formerly had the background property bg.xml now gets a new drawable.

here two pics ... (my repution is to low now :( )

edit: 01.27.15
I got the thing working with saving the values in sqlite db and retrieving the settings from the db. Now i have to load the values in each oncreate of the activities depending on the condition of my boolean pref useCustomGraficSettings. 
Isn't there a more elegant way to solve the task?

Comment: Upto which I understood your question, you basically wants to know where you can save the settings of drawable which user sets? I think you can create JSON of data set by user and can save them in shared preference

Comment: i'll edit my question trying to be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

> i've searched a lot

No, you did not. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

Comment: first of all: thanks for downvoting... it really helps to motivate to ask questions again
secondly i dont really see a solution to my problem there...